# Display value of the database when hovered

Tags: php, jquery, hover

I would like to do a calendar of events for my website. On the calendar I want to display the whole event_description on a certain date when hovered. But I don't know how. I've used jquery and  mysqli for the Hover and retrieval of data.

Here is the image of my current Project
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNgZM.jpg

I have a database which includes "event_id, event_title, event_date and event_description"

This is how I get my value from the database.

```
    while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()) {
        $event_id=$r['event_id']; //This is a unique ID from my DB
        $event_title=$r['event_title']; //Obvious title is obvious
        $event_desc=$r['event_desc']; // I want to post this on the popbox at the bottom
        echo $event_title."<br />";
    <a class='popper' data-popbox='pop2' href='viewEvent?id=$event_id'>See more</a><br />";
    echo "<div id='pop2' class='popbox'>";
    echo " <h2>Event for today!!</h2>";
    echo " This text should have the 'event_description'";
    echo "</div>";
```

div ID pop2 and class popbox are the code for when a link is hovered. This is the script

```
    $(function() {
    var moveLeft = 0;
    var moveDown = 0;
    $('a.popper').hover(function(e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);
    }, function() {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).hide();
    });
    $('a.popper').mousemove(function(e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
    maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
    windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
    windowRight = 0;
    maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);
    if(maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight)
    {
    leftD = maxLeft;
    }
    topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
    maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
    windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) +                parseInt($(window).height()));
    maxTop = topD;
    windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
    if(maxBottom > windowBottom)
    {
    topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
    } else if(maxTop < windowTop){
    topD = windowTop + 20;
    }
    $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);
    });
    });
```

Please tell me what code would you like to see to help me cracking this nut. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: http://www.designer-daily.com/jquery-prototype-mootool-tooltips-12632 ?

Comment: a simple way would be to call an ajax on hover and show the retrieved description in a tooltip , another approch if the events are not too many is you store all the events in javascript array datewise and on hover , filter the array by date

Comment: Hi! Joachim, I've visited the site and there is a bunch of tooltips! I think my solution will be AJAX right? But I don't have a single knowledge about AJAX calls and things regarding to that.

Comment: Hi minas! That is my first choice actually! I would love to use that array approach but I guess I have to assume that there will be tons of events to be stored in this array. Do you think the array calls can handle it?

Comment: for array approach load events only for the current month in the calender, when month changes on calendar you can call ajax to load events for that month in the array

Comment: hmm... I have next to no knowledge about Ajax, and I'm really new to this PHP mySQLi thing, just for a course project at my school, my teachers said that just being simple about this can be passed. But I would really love to learn about Ajax and how can I pull this one off. Do you have pointers minas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow these steps

(1). you should have a hover event like below

eg.

```
$(".popper").hover(function(){
//.load should be here
$('#pop2').fadeIn(800);},function(){$("#pop2").fadeOut(800);});
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/21/

(2). now what you need to do is , show data block using .load

example

```
$( "#pop2" ).load( "getevent.php", { eventid: <?php echo $event_id; ?> }, function() {alert( "done" );});
```

passed eventid as parameter to getevent.php.

read more at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I have the hover on my "link" but the problem is I can't get to pass the data in my database to show it in the message on the hover box.

Comment: i have edited the above jsfiddle pls check it.
 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/21/)

Comment: hmm.. I do have the hover now and the load that I added did nothing. I'm really stumped here :(

Comment: YES~!
I've been able to display one content on both of my links.

I just need to do that on other links!

pop2 is on a while loop and as long as there is an event there will be many pop2. So I need to display their corresponding description depending on their date!

We're CLOSE! Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: **An id should only be used once on a single document.**
multiple pop2 id should not exist on a page...

Comment: ohhh, so I should also change the code for posting right around here?
 eventid: <?php echo $event_id; ?> }

Comment: remove id pop2 from your code.(from div id as well as data-popbox='pop2')

check this how i did it using class :- check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/23/)

Comment: if I delete the div ID how can I get the ajax call to pass and get the data from the dabatase of POP2?

Comment: I made my id from pop2 to $event_id so that every time I loop I will get a different ID(id from the database). How will I pass this ID when I hover the description?

Comment: [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/26/) i guess its the final solution and you'll get it.